# are full privilegies on phpmyadmin correct?

Tags: permissions, unix

I've just realized that my phpmyadmin has full privilegies (to guest also).

See screenshot:[image]

However phpmyadmin is actually a link to another directory in my unix system. Is that normal or should I change the settings ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's normal. The permissions of symbolic links look like that. To see the permissions of the target, you need to dereference the link:

```
ls -ldH phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. But check the permissions of linked directory.
Read (and Execute for directories) permissions are enough for phpMyAdmin.